# Django left join with and condition

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have 3 models `Product,Photo,ProductLikeDislike`. I am left joining all the three. For that I wrote this query:

```
x=Product.objects.values_list('name','photo','productlikedislike')
```

Through this I am getting correct left join I printed and checked like this:

**Note**: `olx` is the name of my Django app.

```
print(x.query)

SELECT "olx_product"."name", "olx_photo"."id", "olx_productlikedislike"."id"
 FROM "olx_product" LEFT OUTER JOIN "olx_photo" ON ("olx_product"."id" = 
"olx_photo"."reference_id_id") LEFT OUTER JOIN "olx_productlikedislike" ON 
("olx_product"."id" = "olx_productlikedislike"."product_id_id") ORDER BY 
"olx_product"."created" DESC
```

Now I want to add extra `and` condition along with `ON` statement like this:

```
ON ("olx_product"."id" = 
    "olx_productlikedislike"."product_id_id"
and "olx_productlikedislike"."product_liked_by_id"=2)
```

So for this somebody suggested me that use Django's `FilteredRelation`. I used but it is not adding extra `and` condition along with `ON`

I used `FilteredRelation` like this:

```
x=Product.objects.annotate( 
productlikedislike_product_liked_by_id=FilteredRelation('productlikedislike',
condition=Q(productlikedislike__product_liked_by_id=2))).values_list('name',
'photo','productlikedislike')
```

but getting the same sql query no extra `and` condition. I am using Django 2.1.5

Comment: as i know you can get the same result by using where condition, so you can try use the objects filter.

Comment: I want to add extra AND condition along with left join as I mentioned there filter will not work if I use filter it will apply where condition to the whole resultset that I don't need

Comment: try to compare the results in the sql with join `AND` and where

Comment: I did it is different

Comment: can you provide some data to your question with sql results?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer by adding `'productlikedislike_product_liked_by_id'` to the `values_list(...)` that I am using along with `FilteredRelation`.

So the final query is:

```
x=Product.objects.filter(Q(photo__cover_photo_flag="yes")|Q(photo__file=None)).annotate( 
productlikedislike_product_liked_by_id=FilteredRelation('productlikedislike',condition=Q(pr
oductlikedislike__product_liked_by_id=2))).values_list('name','photo','productlikedislike_p
roduct_liked_by_id')
```

I printed it it is giving me this resul which I wanted to get:

```
SELECT "olx_product"."name", "olx_photo"."id", 
productlikedislike_product_liked_by_id."id" FROM "olx_product" LEFT OUTER JOIN 
"olx_photo" ON ("olx_product"."id" = "olx_photo"."reference_id_id") LEFT OUTER JOIN 
"olx_productlikedislike" productlikedislike_product_liked_by_id ON ("olx_product"."id" =
 productlikedislike_product_liked_by_id."product_id_id" AND 
(productlikedislike_product_liked_by_id."product_liked_by_id_id" = 2)) WHERE
 ("olx_photo"."cover_photo_flag" = yes OR "olx_photo"."file" IS NULL) ORDER BY
 "olx_product"."created" DESC
```